# Comparar semelhança de valores de dois arrays é possivél?

Tags: php

string da primeira array`$arr_prim[]` deverá ser nula quando for parecida com da segunda `$arr_sec[]` ,

```
 <?php
    $arr_prim[] = array('2','3');

 //array primaria

    $arr_sec[] = array('1','2','3');

  //array secundaria


   foreach($arr_prim as & $key):
     var_dump($key); 
   endforeach;

   foreach($arr_sec as & $res):
   var_dump($res);
   endforeach; 
   ?>
      /*Ambos irá imprimir 
   array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
   */     

   foreach($arr_prim as $k => $value){
        if($s = array_search($value, $arr_sec)){

        $arr_sec[$k] = null;
        var_dump($arr_sec);

    /*resultado da impressão:
    array (size=3)
        0 => null
        1 => string '2' (length=1)
        2 => string '3' (length=1)
    */

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A questão carece de mais detalhes.

Independente disso fiz um laço de repetição simples onde verifica se o valor de um array existe no outro:

```
$arr_prim = array('1','2','3');
$arr_sec = array('2','3');

foreach ($arr_sec as $k => $v) {
    if ($p = array_search($v, $arr_prim)) {
        echo 'encontrou valor '.$v.' no array primário, na posição '.$p.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
        /*
        Setar valor nulo?
        quem deve receber valor nulo? array primario ou secundario? o array inteiro ou somente a posição onde foi encontrado?
        Se a poição não existir, deve ser criada e setada como nulo?
        */

        $arr_prim[$k] = null;
    }
}
```

> ex se o numero 2,3 do primeiro array é parecido com o 2,3 do segundo
>   array, quero que ele seja nulo

Nesse trecho não está claro se está falando das posições/índices/chaves ou dos valores.
Exemplo,

O array primário e secundário possuem valor 2 e 3.
Isso quer dizer que o array primário deveria ficar assim:

```
array(1, null, null)
```

Outro modo de interpretar a questão é baseado nos índices e não somente nos valores. Mas prefiro não escrever mais códigos até estar bem claro o que precisa ser feito.

Comment: esqueci desse detalhe, eu gostaria de fazer uma condição ex: se encontrar o numero 2,3 no array primeiro ele vira nulo

Comment: Exatamente como vc explicou, gostaria que retorna: array(1, null, null)

Comment: certo... o que tentou fazer desde então?

Comment: Tentei fazer o seguinte @Daniel Omine criar um novo array  `$arr = array('num' => $value);` na sequência fiz uma condição, `if(in_array('num', $value)){ $value['num'] = null; } `

Comment: É quase isso. Quando atribuir o valor nulo, especifique a chave do loop corrente. Editei a resposta, agora que está mais claro. Apenas adicionei o trecho `$arr_prim[$k] = null;`

Comment: a idéia é baseada em seguir usuários, ex: estou seguindo os usuários do `$arr_prim` se existir eles no `$arr_sec` ele vai ser nulo, pois eu não preciso mais resgatar o id do usuário seguido

Comment: testei o `$arr_prim[$k] = null;` mas fez o inverso

Comment: mas não era para o array primário receber os valores nulos quando encontrar valores repetidos no array secundário? E sobre o objetivo de "seguir usuários", talvez se explicar o o objetivo, podemos chegar numa solução completamente diferente e possivelmente melhor

Comment: editei a pregunta o resultado deveria ser `array(1, null, null)` mas foi `array(null, 2, 3)`

Comment: desculpe, mas votei para fechar "como não clara o suficiente"... tentei ajudar mas vc parece disperso nas explicações.

Comment: mesmo assim muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante.

Comment: não sendo chato estou procurando solução e até hoje nada, eu gostaria que o resultado fosse exatamente: array(1, null, null), usei o in_array , array_search e nao teve êxito

Comment: Faça um tour : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour